# Maintain div aspect ratio according to height

Tags: css, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

I need to maintain the **width** of an element as a percentage of its **height**.  So as the height changes, the width is updated.

The opposite is achievable by using a % value for padding-top, but padding-left as a percentage will be a percentage of the width of an object, not its height.

So with markup like this:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

I'd like to use something like this:

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
}
.inner {
    padding-left: 200%;
}
```

To ensure the box's **aspect ratio is maintained according to it's height**. The height is fluid because of it's % margin - as the window's height changes, the box's height will too.

I know how to achieve this with JavaScript, just wondering if there's a clean CSS-only solution?

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Comment: And a 'so' answer that may be useful: [height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445491/height-equal-to-dynamic-width-css-fluid-layout/6615994#6615994). also: [css-only-proportional-resizing-of-elements](http://wellcaffeinated.net/articles/2012/12/10/very-simple-css-only-proportional-resizing-of-elements/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizing width of an element as a percentage of its height or vice versa in a fluid design?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569322/sizing-width-of-an-element-as-a-percentage-of-its-height-or-vice-versa-in-a-flui)

Comment: Thanks - I did spot those similar questions, but some refer to ratio the wrong way round and anyway none of the answers helped.  I I thought it would be useful to have a more specific question relating only to width as a percentage of height.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can simply use the [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) property:

```css
.box {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #3CF;
  aspect-ratio: 2 /1;
}
/* for demo only */
body {
  font: medium sans-serif;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.demo {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  outline: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <div class="box">
    <ul>
      <li>This box has fluid height of 50%</li>
      <li>It has an aspect ratio of 2:1</li>
      <li>Resize the container vertically (or horizontally)</li>
      <li>The box will maintain its aspect ratio</li>
      <li>The text content will not affect its width</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Loading an image is fine for this interesting situation. I have resorted to using the same sized spacer.gifs, with responsive css, and various sized images for background swapping when the viewport got larger. It was fast and effective.

Comment: Wow - fantastic solution, thank you! I always avoid adding unnecessary markup, but this requirement is important enough to make it worth it on this occasion.  Marked as answer.

Comment: When changing height of div.box in runtime, width doesn't change accordingly in Chrome 56.

Comment: It should be noted that the above demo doesn't work in Edge/IE on resizing the page – only on refresh.

Comment: This is GENIUS! Thank you.

Comment: one could replace the img element with `<canvas width="1" height="1"></canvas>` or whatever dimensions

Comment: Someone have to edit this post and undo the accepted answer. It is the end of 2021 and better solution is to use `aspect-ratio` css property as answered down the bottom of the thread already. Imagine people coming here and jumping straight to the accepted, most upvoted answer ‍♂️

Answer (score 20):

You can use vh units for both height and width of your element so they both **change according to the viewport height**.

> **vh** 
>       1/100th of the height of the viewport. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length))

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/1u4h3aau/)**

```css
.box {
    position: absolute;
    height:50vh;
    width:100vh;
    bottom: 0;
    background:teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Nice! That's smart! It's not exactly the question, but could be solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question. The OP clearly stated `maintain the width of an element as a percentage of its height` not  the height of the viewport.

Comment: @HashemQolami yes, this will work only if the height of the element is set according to the viewport height. But I am not aware of any other css solution to do this.

Answer (score 10):

There is another, more efficient way to achieve constant aspect ratio according to height.

You can place an empty svg so you dont have to load an external image.

*HTML code:*

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      height="100"
      width="200"
      class='placeholder-svg'
    />
```

*CSS code:*

```
.placeholder-svg {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Change width/height to achieve desired aspect ratio.

Keep in mind, the svg might overflow.

`http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` is just a namespace. It doesn't load anything.

If you change `placeholder-svg` class to:

```
.placeholder-svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

then height is adjusted according to width.

[**Demo 1**](https://codepen.io/Omnivoree/pen/RwwwKxL) Width is adjusted according to height and 2:1 aspect ratio.

[**Demo 2**](https://codesandbox.io/embed/constant-aspect-ratio-xg4b6?fontsize=14) same as above, but you can resize easily (uses React)

Comment: Works like a charm! Exactly what I needed since I'm using a background-image on a div and this solution works both ways (unlike the `padding-top: 100%` option).

Comment: Nice solution, however height can't really be a percentage value.

Comment: Beautiful solution <3

Answer (score 8):

The CSS trick you wrote, works pretty well to keep ratio `width` / `height` on an element.
It is based on the `padding` property that, when its value is in percent, is proportional to parent width, even for `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`.

There is no CSS property that could set an horizontal sizing proportionally to the parent height.
So I think there is no clean CSS solution.

Answer (score 5):

As of 2021 there is a property called `aspect-ratio`.
[Most browsers support it](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio)

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 8px;
}

.box {
    width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    resize: horizontal;
    overflow: auto;
}

.inner1 {
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}

.inner2 {
    aspect-ratio: 3/1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="inner1"></div>
  <div class="inner2"></div>
</div>
```

Run this snippet and resize the outer div manually to see the inner divs behavior

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a pure CSS solution.

**Edit 2023-11 W3C ResizeObserver**

I highly recommend the [W3C ResizeObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver), supported by all major browsers since 2020.

You can observe the height of an element, then set the element's width in the callback.

---

**Original response using "ResizeSensor" lib**

Here's a solution using the [CSS Element Queries](http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/) JavaScript library. This clever library adds invisible elements to the DOM and listens for scroll events on them.

```
var aspectRatio = 16/9;
var element = document.querySelector('.center');
function update() {
  element.style.width = (element.clientHeight * aspectRatio) + 'px';
}

new ResizeSensor(element, update);
update();
```

[CodePen demo!](http://codepen.io/nealehardt/pen/aWbGeL)

Answer (score 0):

#### 2023 Answer

```css
.some-parent-with-changing-height {
   position: fixed; 
   bottom: 0; 
   top: 0; 
   left: 0; 
   right: 0; 
}

.element-that-keeps-ratio {
   background-color: blue; 
   height: 80%; 
   aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-parent-with-changing-height">
   <div class="element-that-keeps-ratio">
   </div>
</div>
```